ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.train_eval'
code and error:
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/content/drive/MyDrive/code/utils')
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/code/utils')

# Importing necessary libraries
import torch
import shutil
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from torch import optim
from transformers import MBartForConditionalGeneration

# Importing custom modules
from indobenchmark import IndoNLGTokenizer
from utils.train_eval import train, evaluate
from utils.metrics import generation_metrics_fn
from utils.forward_fn import forward_generation
from utils.data import MachineTranslationDataset, GenerationDataLoader

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-3287ba1594f5> in <cell line: 19>()
     17 # Importing custom modules
     18 from indobenchmark import IndoNLGTokenizer
---> 19 from utils.train_eval import train, evaluate
     20 from utils.metrics import generation_metrics_fn
     21 from utils.forward_fn import forward_generation

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.train_eval'

I have installed the dependencies manually using pip, but still ModuleNotFoundError: There is no module named 'utils.train_eval'. please help me who know how to solve this error.
I installed this before.
!pip install utils
import utils

code and error must be both in plain text, not images

The utils pip module is at least five years old.  Are you sure this is the module you meant to use?

utils is a pretty generic name -- I suspect you meant to use some other module that unfortunately has the same name.

@JohnGordon yes, bcs If I don't use utils, I don't know what to use. So, what should I do, sir? Do you have any suggestions?

Did you fully write this code yourself, or did you copy it from an example?

@JohnGordon I got this code from another github, I want to try to run it. but it turns out that when I run it on my colab, it gets an error.

sys.path.append('/content/drive/MyDrive/code/utils') This suggests that utils is  a local module on your computer.  Is this the case?

If you got it from another github, then you need to use the same utils module they used, whatever that is.

@JohnGordon yes, it is my local module in my computer. and I use the same utils module as in github.
